# Prove that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $\operatorname{span} (\{v, Av\})$ has dimension $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$.

$$\operatorname{span} (\{v, Av\}) = av + bAv = (a + bA)v $$

If the dimension is $1$, then it wouldn't be equal to zero so I  don't understand how to prove it.

Comment: $v$ is an eigenvector of $A \implies Av= \lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in F$. What can you say about $v$ and $Av$ now?

Comment: The expression $\span(\{v,Av\})=...$ you write in the question is conceptually wrong. The first term is a set while the second and third terms are a vector.

Answer (score 0):

"$\Rightarrow$":$\DeclareMathOperator{span}{span}$

For an arbitrary linear combination from $\span(\{v, Av \})$ one has
$$
c_1 v + c_2 Av = c_1 v + c_2 \lambda v = (c_1 + \lambda c_2) v 
\in \span(\{v\})
$$
where the property of an eigenvector $A v = \lambda v$ was used. 
This means
$$
\span(\{v, Av \}) \subseteq \span(\{v\})
$$
On the other hand, choose a linear combination with $c_2 = 0$, we have
$$
\span(\{v, Av \}) \supseteq \span(\{v\})
$$
so we have
$$
\span(\{v, Av \}) = \span(\{v\})
$$
Because $v$ is an eigenvector we have $v \ne 0$. This ensures
$$
1 = \dim \span(\{v\}) = \dim \span(\{v, Av \})
$$

"$\Leftarrow$":

$$
\dim\span(\{v, Av\}) = 1
$$
means
$$
\span(\{v, Av\}) = \span(\{ u \})
$$
for some $u \in V \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

So for an arbitrary linear combination from $\span(\{v, Av \})$ there must exist a scalar $c$ which allows us to write
$$
c_1 v + c_2 A v = c u
$$
We pick a linear combination with $c_1 \ne 0$ and $c_2 = 0$ and get 
$$
c_1 v = c u \iff \\
v = \frac{c}{c_1} u = \alpha u
$$
so $v$ is a scalar multiple of $u$.

If we had $v = 0$ then the linear combinations from $\span(\{v, Av \})$
would reduce to
$$
c_1 v + c_2 Av = c_1 0 + c_2 A 0 = 0
$$
because $A$ is linear and the span would consist only of the null vector, which would contradict $\dim \span(\{v, Av \}) = 1$. So we have $v \ne 0$. Further this implies $\alpha \ne 0$ because we had $u \ne 0$.

We pick a linear combination with $c_1 = 0$ and $c_2 \ne 0$ and get
$$
c_2 Av = c u \iff \\
Av = \frac{c}{c_2} u = \frac{c}{c_2 \alpha} v = \lambda v 
$$
so $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: I think you have to investigate a bit more on the "$dim=1\Rightarrow v$ is an eigenvector"-direction: one has to discuss the cases $v=0$ and $Av=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the "iff".

Answer (score 0):

If the Span of $v$ and $Av$ has dimension $1$, then the column space is a line.

We also have that the rank of $({v_1,v_2....v_n})<n$ iff the vectors are linearly dependent.

We then let $\displaystyle \lambda=-\frac{k_1}{k_2}$.

Therefore, the vectors $v$ and $Av$ are linearly dependent, meaning that $k_1v+k_2Av=0$ for $(k_1, k_2) \in \mathbb R$.

Setting

That means that $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $v$, where the scalar is $\lambda$.

By definition of eigenvalue, $Av=\lambda v$, so $v$ must be an eigenvector of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $v \neq 0$, the span of $\{v,Av\}$ is one-dimensional iff $\{v,Av\}$ is linearly dependent. Indeed, the only possible dimensions for for the span of $\{v,w\}$ are $0$, $1$, and $2$: $0$ if both vectors are zero, $1$ if they are linearly dependent but at least one is nonzero, and $2$ if they are linearly independent.

Now two vectors $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent iff one is a scalar multiple of the other. For $w=Av$ and $v \neq 0$, this is equivalent to saying that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.